# Why is ASP.NET HttpContext.Current not set when starting a task with current synchronization context

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I was playing around with asynchronous features of .NET a little bit and came up with a situation that I couldn't really explain. When executing the following code inside a synchronous ASP.NET MVC controller

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
        var ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        //ctx == null here
},
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
);

t.Wait();
```

`ctx` is `null` within the delegate. Now to my understanding, the context should be restored when you use the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` task scheduler. So why isn't it here? (I can, btw, see that the delegate gets executed synchronously on the same thread).

Also, from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.THREADING.TASKS.TASKSCHEDULER.FROMCURRENTSYNCHRONIZATIONCONTEXT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), a `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` should behave as follows:

> All Task instances queued to the returned scheduler will be executed
>   through a call to the Post method on that context.

However, when I use this code:

```
var wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);

SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(s=> {
    var ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    //ctx is set here
    wh.Set();
    return;
},null);

wh.WaitOne();
```

The context is actually set.

I know that this example is little bit contrived, but I'd really like to understand what happens to increase my understanding of asynchronous programming on .NET.

Comment: Do you have any documentation supporting your claim that "the context should be restored when you use the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() task scheduler"?

Comment: @Jon I guess it's not in the docs, I assumed it because 1) it seemed reasonable 2) I expected (but didn't verify) that in an async Action you would have access to HttpContext.Current after an await, and since async/await is implemented using the SynchronizationContext I felt it had to be done through that. However, it turns out HttpContext.Current is null after an await. 3) SynchronizationContext.Current.Post preserved it (but I guess this would also happen if it doesn't touch it at all). I guess the answer is that HttpContext.Current isn't preserved by the SynchronizationContext.

Comment: Exactly. Basically your assumption is invalid, I'm afraid. Now, given that, it's not clear what remains to be answered.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the context to be null! The Task is being executed synchronous and the context must be valid throughout the request!

Comment: @Jon basically I think the assumption might be reasonable given that "All Task instances queued to the returned scheduler will be executed through a call to the Post method on that context." But question is why does the current SynchronizationContext not equal the LegacyAspSychronizationContext in first case? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: @Ngm: Yes, I agree - there's something odd going on. I'd investigate it further myself, but I don't know enough about ASP.NET...

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated my answer with further details

Answer (score 8):

***Your observations seem to be correct, it is a bit puzzling.***
You specify the scheduler as "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()". This associates a new "SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler". Now if you look into this class it uses:
[image]

> So if the task scheduler has access to the same "Synchronization
>   Context" and that should reference
>   "LegacyAspNetSychronizationContext". *So surely it appears that
>   HttpContext.current should not be null.*

In the second case, when you use a SychronizationContext (Refer:[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)) the thread's context is shared with the task:

> "Another aspect of SynchronizationContext is that every thread has a
>   “current” context. A thread’s context isn’t necessarily unique; its
>   context instance may be shared with other threads."

SynchronizationContext.Current is provided by LegacyAspNetSychronizationContext in this case and internally has a reference to HttpApplication.

When the Post method has to invoke registered callback, it calls HttpApplication.OnThreadEnter, which ultimately results in setting of the current thread's context as HttpCurrent.Context:

[image]

All the classes referenced here are defined as internal in the framework and is making it a bit difficult to investigate further.

PS: Illustrating that both SynchornizationContext objects in fact point to "LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext":
[image]

Comment: Nice work! IIRC HttpContext.Current is stored on the CallContext, not the TLS. Also I guess the question is whether HttpContext.Current is part of the "thread's context", which it seems it's not. How did you figure "which ultimately results in setting of the current thread's context as HttpCurrent.Context"?

Comment: Yes (I have changed my answer), but if you check both the the tasks should be executed using "SychronizationContextTaskScheduler.QueueTask, which calls m_synchronizationContext.Post. m_synchronizationContext is set using SynchronizationContext.Current earlier in the ctor of "SychronizationContextTaskScheduler". So it should refer to "LegacyAspNetSychronizationContext"

Answer (score 1):

I was googling for HTTPContext info some time ago. And I found this:

http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx

It's about threading and HTTPContext. There is good explanation:

> The CallContext provides a service extremely similar to thread local storage (except CallContext can perform some additional magic during a remoting call). Thread local storage is a concept where each logical thread in an application domain has a unique data slot to keep data specific to itself. Threads do not share the data, and one thread cannot modify the data local to a different thread. ASP.NET, after selecting a thread to execute an incoming request, stores a reference to the current request context in the thread’s local storage. Now, no matter where the thread goes while executing (a business object, a data access object), the context is nearby and easily retrieved.
>
> Knowing the above we can state the following: if, while processing a request, execution moves to a different thread (via QueueUserWorkItem, or an asynchronous delegate, as two examples), HttpContext.Current will not know how to retrieve the current context, and will return null. You might think one way around the problem would be to pass a reference to the worker thread

So you have to create reference to your HTTPContext.Current via some variable and this variable will be adressed from other threads you will create in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would work, but still kind of a hack since you have to keep track of whether you are still in a http context yourself (delegate might be executed when request is already processed). HttpContext.Current !=null would tell me I'm still executing code associated with a request. I assumed that the SynchronizationContext was used for this, but it seems it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are odd - are you sure there's nothing else going on?

---

Your first example ( with `Task` )  only works because `Task.Wait()` can run the task body "inline".

If you put a breakpoint in the task lambda and look at the call stack, you will see that the lambda is being called from inside the `Task.Wait()` method - there is no concurrency. Since the task is being executed with just normal synchronous method calls, `HttpContext.Current` must return the same value as it would from anywhere else in your controller method.

---

Your second example ( with `SynchronizationContext.Post` ) will deadlock and your lambda will never run.

This is because you are using an `AutoResetEvent`, which doesn't "know" anything about your `Post`. The call to `WaitOne()` will block the thread until the `AutoResetEvent` is `Set`. At the same time, the `SynchronizationContext` is waiting for the thread to be free in order to run the lambda.

Since the thread is blocked in `WaitOne`, the posted lambda will never execute, which means the `AutoResetEvent` will never be set, which means the `WaitOne` will never be satisfied. This is a deadlock.

Comment: Actually, both run synchronously, so there is no deadlock. I guess SynchronizationContext.Post 'detects' that it's already on the right context and executes it synchronously.